# Can I delete CBS Persist Logs from Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

My Windows 2008 R2 Server is out of disk space for a week. I checked everything on Server.

The Winsxs folder takes about 17GB, and Log files is about 3GB.

There is a 2GB file under C:\Windows\Logs\CBS namely CbsPersist_20180312074749.log

Can I delete this log file safely, and clear the Winsxs folder (I am planning to delete the files Last accessed before 2011) ?

Comment: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askpfeplat/2014/05/13/how-to-clean-up-the-winsxs-directory-and-free-up-disk-space-on-windows-server-2008-r2-with-new-update/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can safely delete logs in c:\windows\logs\CBS, but don't touch WinSxS, your server won't boot if you mess with the folder's content.

You can try to follow the steps shown here to reclaim disk space and learn more about WinSxS:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2795190/how-to-address-disk-space-issues-that-are-caused-by-a-large-windows-co